# https blocks all http content on my website?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I got a certificate and am currently trying to set up https.

However, I've got a problem : all the content from http source (not https) is blocked :

[blocked] The page at xxxxx ran insecure content from http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css

I saw many https site with pictures not hosted on the certified server. How can I allow this ?

Thanks for the help !

Here is my conf :

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache/conf/ssl.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache/conf/ssl.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/apache/conf/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/apache/conf/ca.pem
```

Comment: Inherently safe types may be safe to load from an insecure server, but types that are not inherently safe pose a threat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing you can do on your end. Some browser block insecure content on secure pages as they can be a security risk (someone could [MITM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) an insecure JavaScript file and steal data, for example).

The Boostrap CDN supports HTTPS just fine:
https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css